# How can I break-down my monolithic queries to more modular and manageable components?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq, azure-functions

### **Background**

Im working on the **.Net Core - C#** backend for a portal that allows users to perform filters & queries on data. This takes the form of backend endpoints which receive the selected list of filters and/or queries through query params, returning the relevant data based on those params. The call to the database to pull the relevant data is done in a massive unreadable where clause that is completely impossible to grasp. Im fairly new to this domain and the technologies used here. Thus I'm hoping to better understand what can be done to break this down to something more manageable.

- Entity Framework Core 3.1 & MS Sql Server.

### **Details/Examples**

***Example Query**:*

```
List<OrderEntity> entities = context.Order.Where(o => 
                    // List built in another query that takes place first
                    ((!regionFilter.Any() && !districtFilter.Any()) || locationFiltersToLocationIdList.Contains(o.locationId)) &
                    // Many more statements...
                    (!orderorderStatusList.Any() || (orderStatusList.Contains("Paid") && o.Status == "Paid") 
                                                 || (orderStatusList.Contains("Late") && o.Status != "Paid" &&
                                                     (o.OrderPaymentDueDate != null && DateTime.Compare((DateTime)o.OrderPaymentDueDate, DateTime.Now) < 0) || 
                                                     (o.OrderPaymentDueDate == null && o.OrderDate != null && o.PaymentTerms != null && 
                                                      DateTime.Compare(o.OrderDate.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(o.paymentInterval)), DateTime.Now) < 0))) &&
                    
                    // Above query segment handels status interpretation,
                    // because the status value on a order cannot be fully trusted.
                    
                    // This kind of on the fly 'field value interpretation' is commonly required
                    (dueToDate == null || (o.OrderPaymentDueDate != null && (o.OrderPaymentDueDate != null && DateTime.Compare((DateTime)o.OrderPaymentDueDate, DateTime.Now) <= 0) || 
                                           (o.OrderPaymentDueDate == null && 
                                            o.OrderDate != null && 
                                            o.PaymentTerms != null 
                                            && DateTime.Compare(o.OrderDate.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(o.paymentInterval)), DateTime.Now) >= 0)))
                    
                    // In both segments we handle case where the query doesnt filter OrderPaymentDueDate,
                    // When it does, and when it should but OrderPaymentDueDate is null or empty.
                ).OrderBy(p => o.OrderDate).ToList();
```

Although this doesn't come close to the scale of the queries I'm actually working with, it hopefully conveys the problem. I can't help but feel there must be a more modular and cleaner way to build this query dynamically. Research highlights topics like **[deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution)**, potential packages, and limitless documentation that never seems to go far enough.

**Question:**

Information on what/how large, complex queries like this are typically addressed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of breaking up large queries you need to bring down the size. Instead of doing lots and lots of filtering which can only hurt performance you might want to go to a multitude of seperate readmodels in which data is already filtered. You can use [cqrs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs) for example (without event sourcing to keep the complexity low). Have a LateOrders table  and PaidOrders table for example.

Comment: `Although this doesn't come close to the scale of the queries I'm actually working with` don't write such queries then. EF and LINQ aren't a replacement for SQL. EF is an *ORM*, its job is to load object graphs from storage. A DbContext isn't a model of a database. The query you have has a *lot* of bugs an no-ops. Those `!regionFilter.Any()` will result in dummy expressions like `WHERE 1=1 AND ...`. There's no such reason to create such a catch-all query though. You can append `Where` calls only for the filters that are actually needed, eg `if(p1!=null){ query=query.Where(o=>o.Field1=p1);}`

Comment: The query has bugs that result in full table scans too. `DateTime.Compare((DateTime)o.OrderPaymentDueDate, DateTime.Now) < 0` why do that? Why not just `o,OrderPaymentDueDate < DateTime.Now` ? This will result in a simple `WHERE dateField<@date`. The conversion and comparison though would result in casts that prevent the use of indexes. Assuming they even worked - there's no `Compare` in T-SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I should have clarified this in the original post, apologies. That query will defiantly not work and is not meant to be anything more than a collection of snippets query. Even if the query were written correctly, there is no Order entity, table or context. It is nothing more than dummy data meant to illustrate a complex and long query.

Comment: @ClintCC all the more reason to *not* write such queries. Such tricks are used (and frowned upon) in raw SQL to avoid generating dynamic queries. They're frowned upon because they result in bad performance even when written correctly. With LINQ though you can append `Where` clauses as needed. `AND` is easy: `query=query.Where()` effectively combines conditions with `AND`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Materialize

Until you call a method to *materialize* the query, you can *build* it.
For example

```
var query = context.Order.Where(o => o.Status == "Paid");

if (myCondition)
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.OrderPaymentDueDate != null)
}

// Now materialize the query, result contain the data
var result = query.ToList();
```

### Split queries

For large (slow) queries or for not supported code you can think to execute separately and then union on client-side

```
var query1 = context.Order.Where(o=> o.Field == "Foo").ToList(); // VERY Slow query1 materialized

var query2 = context.Customers.Where(o=> o.Field == "Bar").ToList(); // VERY Slow query2 materielized

var result = from q1 in query1
             from q2 in query2
             join q1.Id equals q2.Id
             select new 
             {
                Q1Id = q1.Id, 
                Q2Is = q2.Id,
                [..]

             }
```

Another example is data manipulations (warning this is true for a small set of data where the client-side code is better than generated SQL code)

```
var execQuery = context.Order.Where(o => o.MyDate > DateTime.Now).ToList(); //Pre-filter on SQL

var result = execQuery.Where(o=> o.MyDate.Month == 4); // Now I can use ALL Linq operations
```

### Views 3.x

You can think to write SQL Views and connect them to EF.

[Source 3.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/#reverse-engineering-of-database-views)

[Source 5.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#flexible-entity-mapping)

```
// Define model
public class MyView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


// Define DbSet
public DbSet<MyView> MyView { get; set; }


// Configure as view, different from EF 3 to 5
modelBuilder
    .Entity<MyView>()
    .ToView(nameof(MyView))
    .HasKey(t => t.Id);

// Call on code
var view = context
        .MyView
        .ToList();
```

### Raw query

If the generated query is not optimized you can also write your own.

*You can use the FromSqlRaw extension method to begin a LINQ query based on a raw SQL query. FromSqlRaw can only be used on query roots, that is directly on the DbSet<>*

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#basic-raw-sql-queries)

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
    .ToList();
```